# Difference between modified post and new post

Tags: posts, customization

I am just trying to find a way to style modified post and new post separately.

I have a site that have software for download, some software have new updates and I manage to bring updated post to main page with this code before my main loop:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=modified&order=desc'); ?>
```

I want to have different style for modified post.

Answer (score 0):

Add a post class when the post modified time doesn't match publish time. Then style it with that class.

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'wpse244651_add_modified_class' );


function wpse244651_add_modified_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if( get_the_modified_time( $post->ID ) != get_the_time( $post->ID ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'modified-post';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```